# Github encoding breaks pdf embedded fonts

Tags: git, pdf, github, doxygen, ghostscript

I am using doxygen with MiKTex and ghostscript to create documentation PDFs. These PDF's git pushed to my github repo. However If they are subsequently pulled back down again (e.g. on a different PC) they fail to open correctly as Adobe warns that it could not properly extract the embedded fonts.

I have found that this may be down to the GitHub transfer as the problem does not occur if I simply transfer the PDF's in question via USB key etc. Info from the Adobe forums seems to indicate that this could be down to the PDFs being wrongly encoded as ASCII when it should be binary.

How can I solve this so that the PDF's open correctly when pulled from the GitHub repo?
Currently my IDE (eclipse) sets the encoding of the PDF files as UTF-8, should this be changed?

Comment: Do you have `core.autocrlf` turned on? That setting will irreversibly corrupt any binary files that Git mistakenly thinks is plaintext.

Comment: I do have it turned on to try fix the removal of newlines in gitignore and bat files, which of course, don't work so well without newlines. How should I reconcile needing autocrlf for some files but not others?

Comment: OK, I added a .gitattributes file with `*.pdf binary` but no change :(

Comment: You supposedly have to force-update those PDF file using the new `.gitattributes` setting, *and do the same on another machine* -- that is, forcibly check the files out into the work tree after fetching from the remote.  And no, UTF-8 is invalid encoding for PDFs: these are 7-bit ASCII strict files which have to be interpreted as binary.

Comment: Ok, so I set my IDE to have the pdf encoding as ISO-8859 instead (thats ASCII, right?) followed the github instruction on gitsttributes for line endings and re-normalizing then pushed to github and did a clean clone on another machine... some linendings have been resolved in other text files but the PDFs still give the same errors regarding embedded fonts.. grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing with the folks at github, it seems that this issue is down to Eclipse changing the encoding of the PDF sometime during the commit or push for some reason.

Using a new repo with GitHub for Windows or Git Bash did not present such problems.